# Does QGIS generate .mxd format files?

Tags: qgis, mxd

When developing urban planning documentation (f.e. a master plan of a territory) each scheme or plan must be collected in a file in .mxd format.

Does QGIS software generate a .mxd file?

Comment: MXD files are created by ArcMap and are not readable by QGIS.  The duplicate suggests workarounds for converting one to a format that QGIS can read.

Comment: To answer your question very simply, no. QGIS can not create those files.

Comment: There is a python script online that converts things to .MXD. Last time, Linked to it, I got a lot of downvotes, as it also brings up a Google ads page. So you will have to search for it yourself! Or threaten to sue your local authority for not allowing open data formats, which they should be allowing in 2021. Indeed, they may be able to point you towards a relevant script if they are insisting on proprietary formats.